# Java make String to encoding String

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

the GET http from the server is:
    // HTTP GET request
    private static List sendGet() throws Exception {

```
    String url = "http://********/ReciveMessage";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header

    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();


    String str = response.toString(); //str is the problem


}
```

I get a String of characters from server,
Which looks like this:

```
str = "\\u05d0";
```

I noticed that I could not decode the string.

So I'd love to know how to make it, to this

```
str = "\u05d0";
```

Comment: Ah, good details added. One more: What is the value of the HTTP response header Content-Type? My guess is JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your server returns nothing but a stream of Unicode codepoints encoded in the form you describe (no raw characters, for example, just codepoints in the form `\u1234`) then the following code will convert such a sequence into decoded characters:

```
public class UnicodeDecoder {

    private static final Pattern UNICODE_CHARACTER_PATTERN =
            Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{2,4})");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String raw = "\\u05d0\\u05d1\\u05d2\\u05d3";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(raw.length() / 7);

        Matcher matcher = UNICODE_CHARACTER_PATTERN.matcher(raw);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String hexCode = matcher.group(1);
            char[] decodedChars = Character.toChars(
                    Integer.valueOf(hexCode, 16));
            sb.append(decodedChars);
        }

        System.out.println("Raw:\n"+raw);
        System.out.println("Decoded:\n"+sb.toString());
    }   
}
```

This example code gives the output:

```
Raw:
\u05d0\u05d1\u05d2\u05d3
Decoded:
אבגד
```

Note that this method is not very efficient. If performance is important then you can rework this to manually take the substring of each `\u1234` sequence and then add the decoded character(s) to your substring. That would remove the cost of the regular expression matcher.

And if your server is returning characters other than Unicode codepoints, then you'll have to move through the server's response character by character, checking for a `\u1234` sequence. Anything which is not a Unicode codepoint sequence should be added directly to your `StringBuilder`; anything which is a Unicode codepoint should be decoded into characters first.

Comment: How I can include ascii Characters as well?

Comment: @yeo4 Do you just mean [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html)? If not, which standard or specification references the use of ASCII that you speak of?

Answer (score -1):

I use Bobulous solution and modify it, and now it's work with ASCII and UTF-8 in the same String:

```
private String Decode(String raw) {
    final Pattern UNICODE_CHARACTER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9A-Fa-f]{2,4})");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(raw.length() / 7);

    Matcher matcher = UNICODE_CHARACTER_PATTERN.matcher(raw);

    while (raw.length() != 0) {
        if (raw.charAt(0) == '\\') {
            matcher = UNICODE_CHARACTER_PATTERN.matcher(raw);
            String hexCode = "";
            char[] decodedChars = null;
            boolean find = false;
            if (matcher.find()) {
                find = true;
                hexCode = matcher.group(1);
                decodedChars = Character.toChars(Integer.valueOf(hexCode, 16));
                sb.append(decodedChars);
            }
            if(find)
                raw = raw.substring(matcher.group(0).length());
            else {
                if(raw.length() > 2) {
                    char c = (raw.charAt(1));
                    raw = raw.substring(2);
                    switch(c) {
                        case 'n':
                            sb.append("\n");
                            break;
                        case 't':
                            sb.append("\t");
                            break;
                        case 'b':
                            sb.append("\b");
                            break;
                        case 'r':
                            sb.append("\r");
                            break;
                        case 'f':
                            sb.append("\f");
                            break;
                        case '\'':
                            sb.append("\\");
                            break;
                        case '\"':
                            sb.append("\"");
                            break;
                        default:
                            sb.append("\\"+c);
                            break;
                    }
                }else {
                    raw = raw.substring(1);
                    sb.append("\\");
                }
            }
        } else {
            sb.append(raw.charAt(0));
            raw = raw.substring(1);
        }
    }       

    return sb.toString();
}
```

UPDATE: add case of \n,\t,etc..

Comment: Where do you get the "{2,4}" from (as opposed to "{4}")? That's not compatible with Java, JavaScript, JSON, C#, ….

Comment: @TomBlodget the syntax `{2,4}` following a character class means "require at least two and at most four characters from the preceding character class", and it is valid within regex patterns in Java, and JavaScript. I've no idea about C#, and I don't know how a JSON block would contain a regular expression.

Comment: This implementation is very inefficient, and would not suit an input string of great length. A new regex matcher object and a new string object are being created for every character and this will cause a lot of garbage to build up. As mentioned in my answer, a serious solution will need to manually parse the input string rather than use regex, and this becomes especially important if you're also going to match and extract literal characters.

Comment: @Bobulous Sure regex is meaningful but the question is what's the format of the input. \u is used in various programming languages and data interchange formats but all the ones I know require 4 hex digits. The HTTP response header Content-Type should be telling. (Yes, the term in the regex is greedy so would parse 4 hex digits as expected but it could be misleading and avoids the fundamental question.)